# c# Save JSON response to Database table

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, sqlbulkcopy

Ok I tried this for a couple of days now.

I'm trying to read JSON response and insert/update it to DB table (already exists) based on a condition from the response. I have created a Console app.

What my JSON looks like:

```
[
{
 "logtime", "2022-10-19T08:50:06.515Z");
 "lat_value", "Some-Latitude-Value");
 "long_value", "Some-Longitude-Value");
 "name", "Name"
 "population", "Population"
 "unemployment_rate", "UnemploymentPercentage"
},
{
 "logtime", "2022-10-19T08:50:06.515Z");
 "lat_value", "Some-Latitude-Value");
 "long_value", "Some-Longitude-Value");
 "name", "Name"
 "population", "Population"
 "unemployment_rate", "UnemploymentPercentage"
},
{
 "logtime", "2022-10-19T08:50:06.515Z");
 "lat_value", "Some-Latitude-Value");
 "long_value", "Some-Longitude-Value");
 "name", "Name"
 "population", "Population"
 "unemployment_rate", "UnemploymentPercentage"
},

...
]
```

Condition is:

```
if(UnemploymentPercentage > 70)  
{
  if(Name matches to NameCol && UnemploymentPercentage != UnemploymentRateCol)
  {  //InsertRecord   }
  else
  {  //UpdateUnemploymentPercentageValue   }
}
```

> What I have tried:

ModelClass.cs:

```
public string LogTime { get; set; }
public string Lat { get; set; }
public string Long { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Population { get; set; }
public decimal UnemploymentRate { get; set; }
```

ControllerClass.cs:

```
    string url = "https://my-url-goes-here.net";
    ModelClass dataModel = new();
    public void JsonParser()
    {
        var clients = new RestClient(url);
        var request = new RestRequest("api/constructorName", Method.Get)
        {
            Timeout = -1
        };
        request.AddHeader("api-key", "myKeyGoesHere");
        request.AddParameter("param1", "someParam");
        RestResponse response = clients.Execute(request);

        if(response.Content != null)
        {
            string result = response.Content;
            _ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ModelClass>>(result);
        }
    }

    public void WriteJsonDataToMSSql()
    {
        

        //var rates = ((JObject)json["feild6"]).Properties().Select(x => new { Feild6 = x.Name, Rate = Convert.ToDecimal(x.Value.ToString()) });


        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();

            using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlCon))
            {
                copy.DestinationTableName = "tbl_name";
                copy.ColumnMappings.Add("LogTime", "logtime");
                copy.ColumnMappings.Add("Lat", "Latitude");
                copy.ColumnMappings.Add("Long", "Longitude");
                copy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                copy.ColumnMappings.Add("Population", "Population");
                copy.ColumnMappings.Add("UnemploymentRate", "Unemployment");
                copy.WriteToServer(output.AsDataReader());
            }

            sqlCon.Close();
        }
    }
```

I don't know how much I am right and what to do next. Please feel free to correct me. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it that's not working for you here? Is there any error?

Comment: @madmonk46: I'm not sure how to write data into sql based on the condition

Comment: Ok, so is the code in `WriteJsonDataToMSSql()` not working? At a glance it seems somewhat correct, is there an error message being given for that code when you try to run it or is there another issue?